# Scheme - Need to replace the value of a list element

Tags: list, variables, scheme, element, racket

My list grabs user input, and creates a list - this list is in characters.

I would like to be able to check if the `(car myList)` is a character like `#\1` or `#\2`, and then change the car of the list into 1 or 2.

I am using DrRacket.

The problem so far has been attempting to call either `(set! (car myList) 1)` or `(list-set! (car myList) 1 )`

Both are undefined references in my environment.

I just started working with scheme today, for a university assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated if anyone has time

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a stack implementation from this site:

http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs201/Fall_2007/materials/pdfs/stacks.pdf

The stack let me , well i guess "mirror" my list.  after i checked what symbol the user input character was, i would just push an appropriate character onto my stack.

```
(define (makeListFromSymbols myList)

  (display "Length of List = ")
  (display(length myList)) (newline)
   (cond

      ((null? myList) 
       (display "LIST IS NULL")(newline)

       (popTheRestOfStack)

       )
      ((eq? #\0 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 0") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\0)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\1 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 1") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\1)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList) )
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\2 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 2") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\2)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\3 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 3") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\3)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\4 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 4") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\4)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\5 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 5") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\5)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\6 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 6") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\6)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\7 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 7") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\7)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\8 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 8") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\8)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\9 (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals 9") 
       (stackForExpression 'push! #\9)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\+ (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals +") 
       (handleAdditionOperator)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\/ (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals /") 
       (handleDivisionOperator)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\- (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals -") 
       (handleSubtractionOperator)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\* (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals *") 
       (handleMultiplicationOperator)
       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\( (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals (")
       (stack1 'push! #\( )

       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      ((eq? #\) (car myList)) 
       (display "Equals )") 

       (popAndTransferUntilLeftBracket) 

       (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList))
       (newline)
       )
      (else (display "Character is invalid")(newline) (makeListFromSymbols(cdr myList)))
      )

  )
```

if anyone ever has similar questions on this, or about my code / functions, email me. ( i think my email is shown on my user page?)

i also have a pseudo code algorithm for conversion of infix to post fix notation (that was the assignment here)

Answer (score 7):

By default, Racket does not provide mutable pairs, and thus no mutable lists either. That means that the values of pairs and lists are unchangeable.

However, you can `(require racket/mpair)`, which, as the name implies, provides mutable pairs. You then use `mcons`, `mcar`, `mcdr`, `mlist`, etc. instead of `cons`, `car`, `cdr`, `list`.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct, but might not be what you want. The more idiomatic Scheme/Racket way to do this would be to write a function that consumes the original input, and returns a new, separate list that has the modifications you want. (This is strongly preferred, hence lists being immutable by default.) So, for instance, you might write

```
(define (numberify-head lst)
  (cond
    [(eq? (car lst) #\1) (cons 1 (cdr lst))]
    [(eq? (car lst) #\2) (cons 2 (cdr lst))]
    [else lst]))
```

Your program would then go something like

```
(let* ([input (read-input-from-the-user)]
       [processed-list (numberify-head input)])
  ;; ... code that uses processed-list ...
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pairs in Scheme are mutable. But you don't mutate them using `(set! (car myList) 1 )`; rather, you would do `(set-car! myList 1)`. You need to first find the pair that you want to mutate, and then call `set-car!` or `set-cdr!` on the pair (once you do `car` or `cdr` on it, that's just accessing the pair and not mutating it).